# HTMLElement.cloneNode doesn't copy DOM Level 3 events

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I have some code using `cloneNode`. I have a DOM container like a `<div>` tag. When I want a new item to be appended to this container, I want clone the container and append the new element to cloned container instead of the original. Finally, I will replace the original with the clone in the document.

But when I implemented this, I found that cloning the object doesn't copy DOM Level 3 events. Can I copy DOM level 3 events? If not, and I have to rebind all event old item, does the `replaceChild` method cause a memory leak?

```
var temp = this.element.cloneNode(true),
    children = this.children,
    len = this.children.length;

for (var i = 0, length = newChildren.length; i < length; i++) {
    children.push(newChildren[i]);
    temp.appendChild(newChildren[i].element);
}

if (this.element.parentNode)
    this.element.parentNode.replaceChild(temp, this.element);

this.element = temp;

var ch = temp.firstChild;
    children[0].element = ch;
    var j = 0;
while (ch = ch.nextSibling) {
    j++;
    if (j > len)
        children[j].element = ch;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean event listeners? They have never been copyable.

Comment: Why do you replace the whole container? Just append a single new element.

Comment: @Bergi: you append new element, I think this is ok when you add a few elements but with many elements, this is a bad thing.

Comment: Nope. If anything, then the "many elements" are the bad thing, not their appending. And cloning your complete container is definitely worse then multiple appends. If you really care, build a DOMFragment and append that. However, if you *need* that probably something else is wrong.

Comment: @Bergi: I just clone this object, append new elements and replace clone object to the DOM. It makes one web browser reflow???

Comment: Appending new elements without cloning and replacing does only one reflow, too.

Comment: @Bergi: Haizz, i want to clone new item but without re-add event listener. Do you have any ideal? Thank you! I can't add new elements easily, for example: if this parent is ul tag, this children must be li, i don't want append this many times.